# OpenCart - cart.php -> product.tpl | Передача переменной

Tags: php, html, ajax, opencart

Добрый вечер!
Интересует такой вопрос, у меня в корзине при добавлении товара пишет общую стоимость товара (Внимание, красным отметил), я хочу сделать такую штуку, чтобы эта ерунда выводилась на  место синего кружка, переменную нашел, получил в лицо ошибку, дальше в растерянности :D

Как быть дальше, как передать переменную из контроллера, знаний в OpenCart не очень много...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно так это дело выглядит:

```
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 op-box qtlabel">
                            <label class="control-label text-decorop" for="input-quantity"><?php echo $entry_qty; ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3  col-md-3 op-box qty-plus-minus">
                        <button type="button" class="form-control pull-left btn-number btnminus" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quantity">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                            </button>
                            <input id="input-quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" size="2" class="form-control pull-left input-number"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
                            <button type="button" class="form-control pull-left btn-number btnplus" data-type="plus" data-field="quantity">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 op-box qtlabel">
                            <?php echo $column_total; ?></td>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="producthr">
                        <div>
```

Comment: прочитайте доки как связать переменную с шаблоном

Comment: @Naumov Переменная связанна напрямую с напрямую принадлежащей ей контроллеру и tpl файлу, а как передать её я понятия не имею, где найти такую информацию тоже, здесь я так понял ловить нечего. Голосуют за закрытие топика, советов не дают))

Comment: у смарти есть метод assign(name, var) но мы незнаем как это переменная попадает в шаблон какой это шаблон и где он инклудиться.

Comment: Уточните вопрос - вам надо именно это число вывести в карте товара? Или вы всё-таки хотите визуально показывать изменение цены при нажатии на плюс/минус.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Да, вывод цены при плюсе и минусе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта задача решается на фронтенде. Добавьте в **catalog\view\javascript\common.js**:

```js
function qty_summ(el,dp){
  var qty = parseInt(el.value);
  var sum_tag = document.getElementById(dp);
  var sum = parseInt(sum_tag.dataset.price);
  sum_tag.innerHTML = sum * qty;
}

function plus_minus(el,qt){ // эта функция для работоспособности примера
  var p = document.getElementById(qt);
  var pval = parseInt(p.value);
  var s = el.dataset.sign;
  p.value = (s == '+') ? !(pval > 98) ? ++pval: 99 : (pval != 1) ? --pval : 1;
  qty_summ(p,'dynamic-price');
}
```

```html
<span data-sign="-" onmouseup="plus_minus(this,'input-quantity');">-</span>
<input id="input-quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" class="form-control pull-left input-number" onchange="qty_summ(this,'dynamic-price');" />
<span data-sign="+" onmouseup="plus_minus(this,'input-quantity');">+</span><br/>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 op-box qtlabel">
  <span id="dynamic-price" data-price="100">100</span>&nbsp;<span>p</span>
</div>
```

Единственное изменение в контроллере **product.php**, которое необходимо внести - разделить цену и знак валюты на две переменные. По-умолчанию Опенкарт собирает цену со заком валюты в одну переменную. Найдите в `catalog\controller\product\product.php`строчку:

```
$data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency'],'',true);
```

И замените её на:

```
$data['currency'] = $this->currency->getSymbolLeft($this->session->data['currency']);
$data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency'],'',false);
```

Тогда ваш блок qtlabel будет примерно следующим:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 op-box qtlabel">
  <span id="dynamic-price" data-price="<?=$price?>"><?=$price;?>
  </span>&nbsp;<span><?=$currency;?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Не ожидал, спасибо большое!